# Sorting array by recent date and only let one date if same day

Tags: javascript

I have an array of date i want to sort it and get only the recent Date

```
["Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:03:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:01:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:53:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:52:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"]
```

The Date are String, i managed to sort them and get what i want but the problem is i get them as Object and not string

```
  datesFiltered = [];
const array = this.users.map(a => a.date)
      for (const date of array) {
          if (!this.datesFiltered.find(d => new Date(d).setHours(0, 0, 0)
            === new Date(dateString).setHours(0, 0, 0))) {
            this.datesFiltered.push(new Date(dateString))
          }
        }
```

Result :

```
    [
 Mon Jul 16 2018 15:32:50 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
 Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), 
 Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) 
    ]
```

instead of :

```
  [
     "Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
     "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)" 
     "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)" 
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Set` for unique dates and based on that filter out those dates for which value exist in `Set` using `Array.filter`

```js
var array = ["Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:03:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:01:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 08:53:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 08:52:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"];
 
 var set = new Set();
 var array = array.filter(a => {
  var d = new Date(a).setHours(0, 0, 0);
  if(set.has(d)) return false;
  else set.add(d);
  return true;
 });
 console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you sir that's it.

Comment: @LisaN - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the dates into strings while pushing

```
datesFiltered = [];
const array = this.users.map(a => a.date)
      for (const date of array) {
          if (!this.datesFiltered.find(d => new Date(d).setHours(0, 0, 0)
            === new Date(dateString).setHours(0, 0, 0))) {
            this.datesFiltered.push(new Date(dateString).toString())
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `reduce` to group the array into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array. Use `map` and `reduce` to loop thru the array and get the highest date of the group.

This will work even the original array is not on order.

```js
var arr = ["Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:03:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 09:01:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 08:53:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Fri Jul 13 2018 08:52:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)","Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.substring(0, 15);
  c[k] = c[k] || [];
  c[k].push(v);
  return c;
}, {})).map(o => o.reduce((a, b) => new Date(a).getTime() > new Date(b).getTime() ? a : b));

console.log( result );
```